# export import AD User Grops and Membership from on Domain to other

Tags: powershell, active-directory

is there a complete Script for an export and import OU Sturcture, AD User, Groups and Membership from one Domain to other. Like from Prod to Test.
I´m looking for something in powershell, as I know, the password are not possible, but thats ok.

Export-
Ou Structure
Users with all attributes
Groups
Groupmembership

Answer (score 0):

This is no complete Powershell script. You can how ever use the Microsoft AD migration tool atet will allow you to do what you need

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56570